# Azure mgmt containerinstance SDK

Tags: python, azure, sdk

Im trying to create a container group with the python SDK.
Creating resource with:

```py
resources = models.ResourceRequests(memory_in_gb=2.0,cpu=1.0)
```

Then getting this error:

```
HttpResponseError: (InvalidRequestContent) The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'memoryInGB' on object of type 'ResourceRequirements'. Path 'properties.containers[0].properties.resources.memoryInGB', line 1, position 174.'.
Code: InvalidRequestContent
Message: The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'memoryInGB' on object of type 'ResourceRequirements'. Path 'properties.containers[0].properties.resources.memoryInGB', line 1, position 174.'.
```

Is the method looking for memoryInGB but the variable is memory_in_gb?
tried to set `resources.memoryInGB = 2`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

`ResourceRequirements` has two attributes; requests (`ResourceRequests`) and limits (`ResourceLimits`).

You probably forgot to add `ResourceRequests` to `ResourceRequirements` after doing:

`resources = models.ResourceRequests(memory_in_gb=2.0,cpu=1.0)`

Example:

```py
resources = models.ResourceRequests(memory_in_gb=2.0,cpu=1.0)
container_resource_requirements = ResourceRequirements(requests=resources)

container = Container(
    name=name,
    command=command,
    environment_variables=environment_variables,
    image=image,
    resources=container_resource_requirements
    )
```